# Removing zero values from pivot table somehow creates another problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pivot-table

I have an assignment from my Python class to mine a set of data consisting CO2 emissions from (almost) all the countries in the world from 1960 to 2011. One of the task i've been working on is to produce a line graph that represents the growth of CO2 production in a specific country, and i'd like to avoid inserting zeros into the graph. Here is the code i've been using.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib as mpl
import seaborn as sn
import numpy as np

# Creating DataFrame
Data = pd.read_excel('CO2 Sorted Data.xlsx')
df = pd.DataFrame(Data, columns=['Year','CountryName','Region','IncomeType','CO2Emission','CO2EmCMT'])
df.replace(0,np.nan,inplace=True)
print(df)

# Creating the Pivot Table
pvt = df.pivot_table(index=['Year'],columns=['CountryName'],values='CO2Emission',aggfunc='sum')

# Creating the Graph
pvt2 = pvt.reindex()
CO2Country = input('Input Country Name = ')
remove_zero=pvt2[CO2Country]
rz1=[i for i in remove_zero if i !=0]
plt.plot(rz1,c='red')
plt.title('CO2 Emission of ' +CO2Country +' (1960-2011)', fontsize=10)
plt.xlabel('Year',fontsize=10)
plt.ylabel('CO2 Emission (kiloton)')
plt.grid(True)
plt.show
```

If i input Aruba for example, output would look like this.
[Line Graph of Aruba](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PADWE.png)

However, the x-axis only shows the 'number' of years on the data requested, not the year itself. I have no clue on what triggers this other than changing the zeroes to NaN, but that doesn't make any sense in my mind. How can i make the x-axis show the true year, as in 1986-2011?

Here is a glimpse of the data:
[image: A little bit of the data]

Comment: Can you try adding 1960 every x value? P.s you can't share files on this site, but you can copy a few table lines just to give a picture of the kind of data you're working with. I suspect someone might come along and delete the link in a second

Comment: do you mean something like x1 = 1960 + x? i haven't tried it, but i do not know how to add value to an array honestly.

Answer (score 1):

To get the output in proper year format, you must enumerate the data first.

So: `data = list(enumerate(rz1, start=1960))`

There are to ways to go about plotting this new data, one is by converting the data into a np Array and transposing, the other is by using the zip function. They both have the same output.

`data = list(zip(*b))`

or

`data = np.array(data).transpose()`

The final code(in the creating the graph section) is:

```py
# Creating the Graph
pvt2 = pvt.reindex()
CO2Country = 'Aruba'

remove_zero=pvt2[CO2Country]
rz1=[i for i in remove_zero if i !=0]
data = list(enumerate(rz1, start=1960))
# data= np.array(data).transpose()

data= list(zip(*data))
plt.plot(data[0], data[1],c='red')
```

s/n: call `plt.show()`, not plt.show

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the pivoting thing, but the following works fine:

```
co2.Year = pd.to_datetime(co2.Year)
aruba = df[df.CountryName = "Aruba"].set_index("Year")
aruba.CO2Emission.plot()
```